# mysql date between today

Tags: mysql, date, between

Table:

- Activity: id, name, date, time, endDate, endTime

Basically I got a query that saids:

```
TODAY:
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE DATE(A.date) = DATE(CURDATE())

TOMORROW:
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE DATE(A.date) = (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)

NEXT WEEK:
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(A.DATE) BETWEEN '" . strtotime('previous saturday') . "' AND '" . (strtotime('previous monday') - 1) . "'
```

The problem is, and I have no idea how to solve it, when the enddate is inserted, it should search between the date and the enddate. So if an activity started yesterday and it will end today, and we select the "today" query, we still want the activity.

Comment: What is the column type column `date`? If is a date, why you need to use DATE for 1 & 2 query?

Comment: You'll want to specify which fields of your table are `NULL`-able (I suppose `endDate` is), and exactly what you want your queries to pull (e.g. Activities beginning or ending on a given date, or activities that were open on a given date, so "today" is between `date` and `endDate` )

Comment: So you want to retrieve all activities that overlap the period of interest?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM activities
WHERE DATE(now()) BETWEEN DATE(A.startdate) AND DATE(B.enddate)
```

the 'between' syntax isn't limited to just `field between val1 and val2`, it can also be `val between field1 and field2` and other arbitrary expression as well.

Comment: Yup, though tis might give improper results if `endDate IS NULL` (not sure)

Comment: `... AND DATE(IFNULL(B.enddate), some_default_value))`?

Comment: Aight that makes alot of sence, but what about if we want to filter the dates between a period already for example, the next weekend: AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(A.DATE) BETWEEN '" . strtotime('next saturday') . "' AND '" . (strtotime('next monday') - 1) . "'" so then we are like BETWEEN(BETWEEN x BETWEEN Y)